# Backbone rest and localstorage

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, coffeescript, local-storage

So currently all my collections and models comes from a server rest api and works fine.

Im using the latest Backbone.localStorage.js

Now I want a couple of models to only save to localStorage. Im not sure what I need to do  here, this is what I have for the model and collecection that I want to use only localstorage with..

```
class Upload extends Backbone.Model
class Uploads extends Backbone.Collection
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'uploads'
    initialize: =>
        @model = Upload
    sync:(method, model, options) =>
        return Backbone.localSync.call(model, method, model, options)
```

So ny collection is always empty after doing

```
model = new Upload(name:foo)
collection = new Uploads
collection.add(model)
console.log collection shows it has one model here, but logging on the sync overide its empty again
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to get the collection to sync, but you can call model.save() to add it to localStorage. Just add the "localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'uploads'" line to your Upload model first.